# script.js file not linked to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I'm trying to replicate this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/s4P2v/) project on my local machine

I have copied the exactly displayed contents of the index.html, script.js, and style.css files on my local machine. Although my local files didn't initially work the desired way (displaying song length, title, etc).

So I added these lines to the top of the html file, so that my script.js file would be linked. I also added a line to my html file so that my downloaded jquery file would be recognized. With these lines added to my html file:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

But when loading my index.html file into my browser, I can choose a file just fine, but none of the javascript content is displayed. I don't think my script.js file is being recognized, because even If I add console.log() lines to the script.js file, they aren't displayed.

How do I ensure my script.js file is correctly linked so that this jsfiddle project works on my local machine the same way it works on jsfiddle?

thank you

Comment: With developer tools open, do any errors display on the console tab when you load the page?  Do you see any 400- or 500-level responses on the network tab when the browser tries to load your JavaScript files?  Are the scripts in the same folder as the HTML file?

Comment: jquery will be dead soon. Don't waste your time with it. Stick with vanilla or es6.

Comment: Are you loading via `file:///` or `http://` url? If it's the former it is likely a script sandboxing issue and you will need to use a simple web server to run it.

Comment: @SimianAngel there are no error in the console tab before or after I choose the file. And the network tab shows "finished" for all responses. All my files are in the same folder, these files are: [index.html, style.css, script.js, jquery-3.3.1.js]

Comment: @Andy - all good web devs know [jQuery is great and does all things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif). long live jQuery.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Have to applaud the image.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. lol.. most places now days won't allow jquery due to its weight. All modern stacks and UI libraries are getting rid of jquery. 
But I do respect those who have a love for it

Comment: @Andy Google, stack overflow, Amazon and tons of other huge companies still use jquery. it's not that heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cdn

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you download the file you have to be sure where is this file in your project

```
<script src="project/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I add the cdn line, so that my html file contains these two lines:    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>            when I run my index.html file I get a message in console saying "   script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:5   "

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Be sure jquery must be the first script tag then you can put all your scripts

Comment: You only have to change the order, first the cdn and then your script.js file

Comment: This removes the console error, but the audio file info like duration  / file name / file type is still not displayed. Thats the part the confuses me, how If it's set up correctly (presumably) that my local machine version does not produce the same result as the jfiddle version. Ive been running my index.html by just opening it in chrome, do I need to test it via hosting on a server instead?

Comment: If you log something in your script.js displays the log?

Comment: Is your script.js in the same folder where lives index.html?

Comment: If not you have to put the correct path to your script.js

Comment: ok i fixed it, turns out moment was a js file i needed to download. everything works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
You need to make sure you have jquery downloaded locally or use a CDN in your html file. See below.
Also, make sure you have your `script.js` in the same folder of your `index.html` or point to the file correctly.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js">
</script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: If I uses these lines, I get an error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:5

Comment: add defer to the end of it

Comment: to the end of what?

Comment: see update, that will wait for everything to load before running your script, so jquery will be loaded into DOM when you script requires it. It works here

Comment: ok with the defer added this displayed the file name, type, and size correctly. But not the duration, and throws an error in the console. Any idea why this might be? What I wanted to gain from playing around with this code was how to get the duration of audio files through a website running html5/javascript

Comment: the error says that " Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined "

Comment: well, thats another question though.

Comment: it uses another library

Comment: You need moment.js, thats what it uses to deal with time.

Comment: the fiddle includes this file too... https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the code, it works. You will now see all the data from the mp3